# How to send actions from View to ViewModel in MVVM architecture in Android

Tags: android, mvvm, architecture, android-architecture-components

Helllo! 
I am working on improving my android architecture skills. I found this [article](https://medium.com/livefront/youre-misusing-mvvm-b0c55e93f338) which says that it is a bad practise to call viewModels functions in view.

For example calling functions in such way is a bad practice.

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    if (v == vk_login) {
        loginViewModel.onVKLoginClick()
    }
}
```

I understand how to use LiveData to transfer data and actions from ViewModel to View. For this we init LiveData in view. But I can't find any information how to send user actions info using LiveData (or smth similar) from view.

Should I init LiveData in view and subscribe view model to it (Sounds strange).

Or is it better to use smth like this:

```
loginViewModel.nameFromUser.value = "some name from text view"
```

Or article which I found is just wrong and it is ok, to call viewModels functions from view?

Comment: are you looking for two way databinding. Like viewmodel needs to know if user is typed something in edttext and clicked a button. If so search for two way databinding. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way

Comment: Thank you, for this link, but I an trying not to use Databinding now. IFor me it is easier to use databinding, than create clean architecture without it. So for educational purpose, in my current project Databinding is prohibited. 
But thank you, I did not know about this feature of Databinding.

Comment: Are you still confused? Have you got the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ViewModel` should never include references to Android frameworks, let alone views, else it will result in a memory leak. It's better to use `loginViewModel.nameFromUser.value = "some name from text view"` it like this.

[image: DEMO]

[Source - ViewModel Patterns/Anti Patterns](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54)

A view can observer live data but the `ViewModel` can not observe views because the views do not emit `LiveData` objects.

Quoting from the docs:

> Caution: A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context. ViewModel objects are designed to outlive specific instantiations of views or LifecycleOwners

Comment: Am I right, that I can call viewModels functions from view? 

For example, code below is clean, right?

        https://pastebin.com/k2SVtUJF

Comment: @VladimirVechkanov yes you can unless you do not pass activity context or anything view related

Comment: Yes, it is safe.